# Bootstrap modal not getting react state

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a `Comp` component and all it does is display a six times, a button which opens up a modal. Below is the code for that.

```
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "../../node_modules/react";

function Comp(props) {
  return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(value => 
    <>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        {`Click button ${value} to open below Modal`}
        {/* The value in the above line is working perfectly fine */}
      </button>

      <div class="modal fade text-white" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Show value</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <h1 className="text-white">{value}</h1>
                  {/* The above value is always zero */}
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>);
}

export default Comp;
```

For each value `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in the array, the `value` is being mapped to each button and the result is as below.

[image: All buttons being displayed with their corresponding value]

All the buttons are being displayed with their corresponding `value`s properly till now as in the image. But when I open the modal, only one value shows up and that is `0` irrespective of which button I click.

In the below image, I clicked the button with `value` as `3` and `0` shows up in the modal.

[image: Modal shows 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have been opening the same modal every time. Button's `data-bs-target` and modal's `id` must be corresponding and unique, so the button with 0 opens a modal with 0, a button with 1 opens a modal with 1 and so on ...  ↓↓↓

This is optional, but you will also need to change all `class` attributes to `className` and give a unique `key` attribute to a wrapping element rendered in every iteration `<div key={"some_key_" + index}>`

```
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "../../node_modules/react";

function Comp(props) {
  return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((value, index) => 
    <div key={"some_key_" + index}>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-success m-2"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target={"#exampleModal" + index}
      >{`Click button ${value} to open below Modal`}</button>

      <div
        className="modal fade text-white"
        id={"exampleModal" + index}
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby={"exampleModalLabel" + index}
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content bg-dark">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id={"exampleModalLabel" + index}>
                Show value
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close btn-close-white btn-sm"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <h1 className="text-white">{value}</h1>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}

export default Comp;
```

In my working demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-obocwa?file=src/App.js), I had to remove all `...-bs-...` from HTML attributes because I am not using any of that, but you have the idea

Comment: Using the array index would be a better option here. If values are repeated `id`s will be same.

Comment: yeah, updated the answer